# How to call a method dynamically in Elixir, by specifying both module and method name?

Tags: erlang, metaprogramming, elixir

I'd like to know what exactly a method name is in elixir:

```
array = [1,2,3]
module_name = :lists
method_name = :nth                  # this not working
module_name.method_name(1, array)   # error, undef function lists.method_name/2
module_name.nth(1, array)           # returns 1, module_name is OK. It's an atom
```

But I can do almost the same thing in erlang:

```
A = [1,2,3].
X = lists.
Y = nth.
X:Y(1,A).  #  returns 1
```

How can I do this in elixir?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `apply/3` which is just a wrapper around `:erlang.apply/3`. It simply [invokes the given `function` from the `module` with an array of `arguments`.](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L307-333) Since you are passing arguments as the module and function names you can use variables.

```
apply(:lists, :nth, [1, [1,2,3]])
apply(module_name, method_name, [1, array])
```

If you want to understand more about how elixir handles function calls (and everything else) you should take a look at `quote` and `unquote`.

```
contents = quote do: unquote(module_name).unquote(method_name)(1, unquote(array))
```

which returns the homoiconic representation of the function call.

```
{{:.,0,[:lists,:nth]},0,[1,[1,2,3]]}
```

You can `unquote` the quoted function call with [`Code.eval_quoted/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L207-330)

```
{value, binding} = Code.eval_quoted(contents)
```

Edit: here is an example using Enum.fetch along with a var.

```
quoted_fetch = quote do: Enum.fetch([1,2,3], var!(item));             
{value, binding} = Code.eval_quoted(quoted_fetch, [item: 2])
```

Comment: Good. So the method name is a atom. Now I think it is just the syntax which don't allow us writing `module.method` in elixir, right?

Comment: I believe you are correct. I think the only way to make this work would be to change the syntax to use atoms when calling module functions (i.e. `:lists.:nth`). I'd rather just use apply in cases like this.

Comment: Can you show how this could be done for a normal elixir function. Something like `Enum.fetch`? Is there variable variables or variable functions?

Comment: quoted_fetch = quote do: Enum.fetch([1,2,3], var!(item));             
{value, binding} = Code.eval_quoted(quoted_fetch, [item: 2])

Comment: I've updated the answer for better formatting. Using var!/1 allows you to substitute a variable inside a quoted method for the value of the  corresponding key in the binding.