# order_by with dynamic value on Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to order by a string provided dynamically. The field I want to order is alias in the select.

```
query
|> select([t], %{orders_count: fragment("? AS orders_count", count(t.id)})
|> order_by(fragment("?", ^field))
```

This will generate this, and will not work.

```
order_by: [asc: fragment("?", ^"orders_count")],
```

But if I put the string name without a variable

```
query
|> select([t], %{orders_count: fragment("? AS orders_count", count(t.id)})
|> order_by(fragment("orders_count"))
```

will generate this, and it works.

```
 order_by: [asc: fragment("orders_count")],
```

But I can't understand why it doesn't work with the first example.

Comment: @mudasobwa, it doesn't compile. It says undefined function `field/0`.

Comment: Wild guess was wrong then :(

Comment: What's the value of `field` here? The string `"orders_count"`?

Comment: @Dogbert, yes. And other possible string values. I can add all fields manually (it's 3), but in terms of code isn't pretty.

Comment: I was trying to get some way to call `fragment("orders_count")` dynamically, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230965/how-to-call-a-method-dynamically-in-elixir-by-specifying-both-module-and-method but I thinks it's way over my head. Ecto is also pretty complex.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because `fragment` doesn't accept a runtime string as the first value to prevent SQL injection. See the error message thrown when you do `order_by(fragment(^field))`.

Comment: If the field is a member of the struct, you can do `order_by([p], field(p, ^:"#{field}"))`.

Comment: It isn't a member of struct, it's on the select with an alias.